# Make camera move constantly upwards in box2d world

Tags: libgdx, box2d

Im using libGdx to develop a 2d game, which has the following:

- The world moves in an upward direction by having a camera follow the player's y position.
- The user only controls player's x movement, the y is a constant speed.

What i want to do now is let the user control the players x and y movement and let the camera move constantly up without following the player.

What is the best way to do this?

This is what i tried:

in Render()

```
player.body.setTransform(fingerPosition.x, fingerPosition.y, player.body.getAngle());

box2dCamera.position.y = box2dCamera.position.y + cameraSpeed;
box2dCamera.update();
box2dSpriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(box2dCamera.combined);
```

This worked but all my collisions stopped working with other box2d bodies. Do i need to update each body in my game with the recalculated camera some-how? How would I do this?

Comment: Why use physics bodies to control something that does not interact with anything physically?

Comment: The player does interact with other bodies, as stated in the question, the collisions stopped working when I tried to do this. @ClassicThunder

Comment: I'm referring to the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to update each body when modifying the camera. Bodies' positions stays the same when you move the camera around. `batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);` already offsets your batch to the right position. The problem must result of this line :

```
 player.body.setTransform(fingerPosition.x, fingerPosition.y, player.body.getAngle());
```

Assuming you are rendering after this line of code and updating your world before, your player will always be positioned to `fingerPosition`, since the world has not been updated between this and rendering.

To make an object follow your mouse/finger, you should use a joint. Get an eye on the [MouseJoint class used in the libgdx box2D testbed](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/joints/MouseJoint.html). You can find how to implement that [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dF5dUiJtYng).